# Zurb Foundation - error setting row width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to adjust row width in my Foundation setup.  In SASS overrides file, I uncomment the following line:

```
$row-width: emCalc(1000);
```

After doing that, I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: -0.9375em*px isn't a valid CSS value.
```

What does this means and how can I address this issue?

Comment: emCalc converts px to em. the error tells that the value is still in px. I guess that emCalc function is not found. Did you import @import "foundation/foundation-global" on your _settings.scss?

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of `emCalc` is:

```
$row-width: emCalc(1000px);
```